# Injecting Iframe and image to html and wait for onload event

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have SOME string coming from the server on some ajax success event:
I want to inject the bellow tags before `</body>` and wait till they are **both** loaded.
After they are both loaded I want to alert something

```
...
,
success : function(data){
    var iframe = "<iframe src='http://blablabla.com'></iframe>";// came as data.iframe
    var image = "<img src='http://blablabla.com' />";//came as data.image
    // how do i inject it to html syncly 
    alert("both iframe an image loaded completely");
}
```

I can use Jquery or native.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like;

**HTML:**

```
<button id='load'>Load image and iframe</button><br />
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#load').on('click', function(){
        var obj=$('<iframe/>', {
            id:'iframe_google',
            src:'http://blablabla.com',
            style:'display:none;width:400px;height:400px',
            load:function(){
                $(this).show();
                var imgPaht = "http://blablabla.com";
                $('<img src="'+ imgPaht +'">').load(function() {
                  $(this).width(1000).height(1000).appendTo('body');
                    alert("Iframe and image loaded");
                })

            }
        });
        $('body').append(obj);    
    });
});
```

I have updated urls and make an example.

You can see working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mw949/1/)